# Fetch user info in comments with graph api

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using PHP SDK to fetch all posts and comments with relative likes from a facebook page. When I try to fetch also the name of the commentators with the property `from`, nothing change. This is the link:

`/me/posts?fields=message,comments.summary(true) {message,from{id,name},likes.summary(true)},likes.summary(true),created_time'`

I still get:

```
"comments" => array:3 [▼
    "data" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
            "message" => "commento al secondo post"
            "likes" => array:3 [▶]
            "id" => "126427989164897_126428849164811"
        ]
    1 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

There is no attribute `from` in the response, as you can see. I have tried a lot of combination but I can see the name and the id of the commentator only if is the page itself.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your app live, or still in dev mode? In dev mode, at most you can expect this to work for comments made by users with a role in the app.

Comment: Yes, I'm in dev mode. There are known restrictions?

Comment: I don’t know if this is specifically documented anywhere, but dev mode is more restrictive now, than it used to be. We are talking about data from users that did not interact with your app at all so far, they did not grant it any permissions. If access to “everything” was still possible in dev mode, then shady people who just try to grab data for impure purposes, could just leave their apps in dev mode, and not bother with the review process at all.